# Find equation of log function given graph

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, transformation

[image]

How would you find the equation of this log graph with respect to

transformation of the function $$ a\log[k(x-d)] + c$$

I had trouble solving this accurately.

Comment: Are you just trying to solve for $a,c,k,d$? What do you mean by "transformation"?

Comment: Yes just to solve for those variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that you need any transform to find the equation of the graph $$y=a\log[k(x-d)] + c$$ First, you can notice the vertical asymptote at $x=-2$; this implies $d=2$.

Next, $y=0$ if $x=8$; this gives $$0=a \log(10k)+c \implies c=-a \log(10k)$$ So , at this point $$y=a \log[k(x+2)]-a\log(10k)=a \log(\frac {x+2}{10})$$

Now, from the graph, if $x=0$, $y=y_0$ ($\approx -2$) from which you can deduce the value of $$a=-\frac{y_0}{\log (5)}$$ and then $$y=-\frac{y_0}{\log (5)} \log(\frac {x+2}{10})$$ In fact, you could pick any point to fix the value of $a$.

I did not do more since, being almost blind, it is quite hard to me to see accurately the values.

**Edit**

You could have notice that the equation can write differently since $$y=a\log[k(x-d)] + c=a \log(x-d)+a\log(k)+c=a \log(x-d)+f$$ which simplifies the problem.